# Why does $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ not equal $\sin^{-1}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=y$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

The equation $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$ does not produce the same output as $y=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: How are you defining $\sin^{-1}$?

Comment: Because computer algebra systems are notoriously neither sound nor complete.

Comment: Consider why $y^2=x^2$ isn't identical to $y=\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: 1. Greek word for two. 2 common english name 3. 20th letter in the alphabet 4. rhymes with something I shouldn't write in here. If you add 1+2+3+4 you'll get the answer of wisdom

Comment: @vitamind can i buy a vowel?  I'm able to compute the summation and count out the alphabet.

Comment: You will get $y=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$ only if $y$ is in the range of arcsine.  Conventionally, $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Does $\sin(0) = \sin(y)$ produce the same result as $\sin^{-1}(\sin(0)) = y$? Why or why not?

Comment: @user2661923 1. is "bi"

Comment: @vitamind I used Java against a list of words, and came up empty on possibly pertinent words starting with "bi" and ending with "ten".  The closest that I came is "bicentric".

Comment: Each number represents some letters. If you put the numbers together (the letters) you'll get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the range $y$ in the explicit function is

$$y=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))\in \left[-\tfrac\pi2, \tfrac\pi2\right]
$$

while the range of $y$ in the implicit function
$$\sin y= \sin x,\>\>\>\>y\in (-\infty, \infty)$$